# Visual Studio doesn't like div tags inside dl tags

Tags: html, visual-studio

It seems Visual Studio 2019 (not tested previous versions) doesn't like `div` tags inside `dl`.

The code copy-pasted from [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) (3rd example) inside an HTML page in Visual Studio gives warnings.

*The following example illustrates the use of the dl element to mark up metadata of sorts. At the end of the example, one group has two metadata labels ("Authors" and "Editors") and two values ("Robert Rothman" and "Daniel Jackson").* **This example also uses the div element around the groups of dt and dd element, to aid with styling.**

[image]

Please note that my VS2019 is up to date.

**What can be done to avoid these specific warnings? And worst, indentation and expand/collapse features are broken**

To reproduce:

- Open Visual Studio 2019
- Add a new HTML page
- Copy/Paste code from [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) (3rd example)
- You'll see all `div` tags with warnings and no expand/collapse on `div` tags. If you replace `dl` with `div` everything is okay then.

If I do the same thing in VSCode, it works just fine.

So, it seems VS2019 doesn't like `dl` with `div` tags inside.

Answer (score 3):

`<div>` is not an allowed content of `<dl>`

> Permitted content
>
> Either: Zero or more groups each consisting of one or more `<dt>`
> elements followed by one or more `<dd>` elements, optionally intermixed
> with `<script>` and `<template>` elements. Or: (in WHATWG HTML, W3C HTML
> 5.2 and later) One or more `<div>` elements, optionally intermixed with `<script>` and `<template>` elements.

src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Comment: Or: (in WHATWG HTML, W3C HTML 5.2 and later) One or more **<div>** elements, optionally intermixed with <script> and <template> elements.

Comment: I may have missed something but it seems div tags are allowed `Or: (in WHATWG HTML, W3C HTML 5.2 and later) One or more <div> elements...`

Comment: It's definitely allowed in the current HTML spec; there's even an example of it being done on the page you linked. This is just Visual Studio being outmoded.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact the message is "Element 'div' requires end tag" (for `<div>`) and "End tag is missing start tag" (for `</div>`), not anyhow related to the `<dl>`, it's just a bug. The wrong `<div>` formatting points to a bug as well.

If you want the bug to be fixed, you should probably try reporting the bug in the MicroSoft-acceptable way (not StackOverflow definitely).

[image: error message]

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

> You can not use `div` in `dl` content. [The Description List element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)

Answer (score 0):

The  tag in HTML is used to represent the description list. This tag is used with  and  tag. So  is not an allowed content of